# In HTML5 audio player play more than one audio

Tags: html5-audio

I am working with HTML5 audio. I have a question. Is it possible to play more than one audio on the same page, same time using HTML5 audio player ?

Answer (score 1):

yes it's possible with multiple `<audio>` tags for example

```
    <audio controls>
      <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
      <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">

    </audio>
    <audio controls>
      <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
      <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Comment: Thanks @Prakash Reddy Potlapadu. Will it play same time more than one player ?

Comment: @abuabu yes it does play multiple audios simultaneously. For testing go to `https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_audio_all` place multiple audio tags and click them